# pulling more cells in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4.2, ios5

I created  navigation based app. In  my tableview with more sections, i want to pull more cells in one section which has 4 cells already last cell is adding action cell after **i clicked add more cells** in the last cell of that section like the **load more cell**,I want to pull another 4 more cells  but i want the same cell in that section to be pulled again. i.e. **The 4 cells repeated will the same as the cells already there**. I researched lot of samples for this none is clear for me. Can any one explain ho can i pull the same type cells .
thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code to show what you have done so far. That will allow us to point out where you are going wrong. Also, have you read Apple's examples and documentations on the subject?

Comment: Actually i done load more cells . i load more cells for the server data to display.if more than some extent. Now i want to repeat the cells i have. i haven't coded that . Where i confused .

Comment: My previous comment still stands. Post some of your code. Otherwise we can't show you where you are making a mistake. We aren't here to do your work for you, but we are willing to help.

Comment: I haven't coded yet . I haven't got any idea for this. any idea plz

Comment: By posting the code of what you HAVE done, then we might be able to help show where you are going wrong. If you just want to have more cells, then this should be obvious if you have READ the documentation from Apple and taken the time to UNDERSTAND it. If you show what you have done, then we might be able to point out where you are going wrong.